# Random Forest issues with Importance

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to construct a random forest for ecological data but keep getting the error

> "no applicable method for 'importance' applied to an object of class
>   "logical".

The code I have is:

```
fit2 <- randomForest(sv ~ salinity + temp + Depthbin +  cdistance + oxygen + 
                      type + diel, data=d.omit, importance(TRUE), ntree=2000)
```

The variable of interest (sv) is continuous, so I'm not sure if that impacts things. When I remove the `importance(TRUE)` portion of the code, I can run the random forest but the IncNodePurity values I obtain are ridiculously high (some values over 100,000!!). I'm hoping the `importance(TRUE)` addition will fix that, but if not, does anyone know of a better way to examine the importance of each variable?

Comment: It is easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Great advice MrFlick. Will make sure to do next time.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
fit2 <- randomForest(sv ~ salinity + temp + Depthbin + cdistance + oxygen + type + diel, data=d.omit, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000)
```

With `importance(fit2)` you should be able to see the variable importance.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. When looking at the output, I receive both %IncMSE and IncNodePurity. Do you know if one is recommended over the other for interpretation/analysis?

Comment: Glad it helped. Maybe [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162465/in-a-random-forest-is-larger-incmse-better-or-worse) can help you answer your question with IncMSE and IncNodePurity